# Peugeot Performance 30 Information

Tags: road-bike, peugeot

Recently bought an old(-ish) Peugeot in need of love and am trying to find out about it.

On the frame, it says Peugeot, Performance and 30. So I assume the model is 'Peugeot Performance 30', but I cannot find much information about it. All I know is what it says on the bike, it's a Columbus frame, Shimano hardware etc. I've tried to find it online, but can only find Performance 1000, say.

I'd just like to have some background on it, what year it was, what it would've been sold for at the time etc. but apparently it's non-trivial so I would really like to hear if you know about it!

Comment: Good pictures increase the chances of an accurate answer. A whole bike shot, close ups of any labels, logos, decals, distinctive aspects of the bike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From searching through [the catalogs](https://labibleduvelocataloguespeugeot1.blogspot.com/) it looks like the [Performance 30 is from 1999](https://labibleduvelocataloguespeugeot1.blogspot.com/p/peugeot-1999.html) (scroll the page not quite to the bottom)

[image]

Comment: Thank you David, that’s excellent!!